# Can't output Channel Images data with Stash

Tags: stash, channel-images

I have the following template that sets values, including a set_list for a Channel Images field, but I can't get the Channel Images data to be displayed in the stash layout;

```
{stash:embed:layouts:page}

{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="shop-pages"
    disable="{global:channel_disable_basic}"
    require_entry="yes"
}
    {exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="3"}
        {stash:meta}{exp:nsm_better_meta:template entry_id="{entry_id}"}{/stash:meta}
        {stash:page_title}{title}{/stash:page_title}
        {stash:page_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:page_entry_id}
    {/exp:stash:set}

    {exp:stash:set_list name="images" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="3"}
        {cf_page_heroes}
            {stash:page_hero_image}{image:url}{/stash:page_hero_image}
            {stash:page_hero_title}{image:title}{/stash:page_hero_title}
            {stash:page_hero_description}{image:description}{/stash:page_hero_description}
        {/cf_page_heroes}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

However, I can't get the Channel Images data to be displayed in the stash layout with the following code (it simply outputs the expressionengine tags);

```
<h1>{exp:stash:page_title}</h1>

{exp:stash:get_list name="images"}
    {stash:page_hero_image}
    {stash:page_hero_title}
    {stash:page_hero_description}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Can anyone advisse what might be wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables inside `get_list` should not be prepended with `stash:` - You only do that when you're getting or setting a single variable directly, but it's your parent `get_list` tag which is doing the getting, so you should just get the vars as:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="images"}
    {page_hero_image}
    {page_hero_title}
    {page_hero_description}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh. More coffee for me. Thanks James.